# Bulk product Importing Error

Tags: import, products

We are in the process of evaluating `Magento CE` and `Cart2Quote` (*Extension for Magento*) 
Not sure if this is a `Magento` issue or `Cart2Quote`

I have installed `Magento CE` (with test data) and are able to integrate `Cart2Quote`. 
We carry a lot of products so we need to do bulk import and export of the products.

To check import and export functionality I am referring to:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-using-magentos-import-export-profiles

I am able to export the product, but when I try to import the same products it gives me following error:

> Invalid value for 'status' in rows: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,
>   12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24 Invalid value for
>   'tax_class_id' in rows: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,
>   15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24 Invalid value for 'visibility'
>   in rows: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
>   18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24 Invalid value for 'gift_message_available'
>   in rows: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
>   18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24 Invalid value for 'page_layout' in rows: 2,
>   7 Invalid value for 'country_of_manufacture' in rows: 2, 7
>
> File is totally invalid. Please fix errors and re-upload file Checked
>   rows: 24, checked entities: 24, invalid rows: 24, total errors: 100

Please note that

1. For some of the test products, I have given (manually from the admin console);

**Allow Quotation Requests**: Yes
**Quotation Conditions**: Always show Add to Quote Button

2. I have added new products (manually from the admin console) with:

**Allow Quotation Requests**: Yes
**Quotation Conditions**: Always show Add to Quote Button

In both the above cases `Car2quote` works fine, as the product shows up in the front end with "`Add to Cart`" button on them.

Can any one help me with the importing issue. Have attached screenshot of the importing error and below is the link for the csv file I am trying to import into the system.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzE4AMByioYxTUF3T3RTTjhLbUE/view?usp=sharing

I tried importing using Data-Flow profiles...it is able to import now....

Thanks

Comment: Are you saving this as a text csv or as an Excel csv? Make sure it is just a text file.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: Why don't you give this extension a try https://magecomp.com/magento-email-cart.html

Answer (score 2):

For bulk importing of products (or bulk updating) I use [MAGMI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/).

After getting it setup, an easy way to get working quickly is to export Attribute Sets using Dataflow Profiles. This will give you a basic template of the information you will be required to use with MAGMI, although the file you've provided is a close match to the MAGMI .csv file format.

MAGMI can easily import thousands of products in a very short amount of time.